# How to extract the url in hyperlinks from a docx file using python

Tags: python, python-docx

I've been trying to find out how to get urls from a docx file using python, but failed to find anything, i've tried python-docx, and python-docx2txt, but python-docx only seems to extract the text, while python-docx2txt is able to extract the text from the hyperlink but not the urls themselves.

Comment: Can you state more specifically what your broader intention is? python-docx has hyperlink capability, so the information your looking for is in there. Are you just looking to extract all the hyperlinks in a document or extract them along with the rest of the text?

Comment: @scanny I only want the URLS, don't care about the text.

Comment: Oops, apologies, python-docx doesn't support hyperlinks yet, it's a pull request that's gotten stalled unfortunately. You'll need to go down to the lxml/internals level if you want to do this. I'll put some ideas in an answer.

Answer (score 12):

I am a beginner on Python and have an assignment to use Python to change each hyperlink in a .docx document. Thanks to Kiran's code which gave me hints to do a few guess, trial and errors and finally get it working. Here is the code I have and like to share with other beginners.

```
# python to change docx URL hyperlinks:
### see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40475757/how-to-extract-the-url-in-hyperlinks-from-a-docx-file-using-python

from docx import Document
from docx.opc.constants import RELATIONSHIP_TYPE as RT

print(" This program changes the hyperlinks detected in a word .docx file \n")

docx_file=input(" Pls input docx filename (without .docx): ")

document = Document(docx_file + ".docx")

rels = document.part.rels

for rel in rels:
   if rels[rel].reltype == RT.HYPERLINK:
      print("\n Origianl link id -", rel, "with detected URL: ", rels[rel]._target)
      new_url=input(" Pls input new URL: ")
      rels[rel]._target=new_url

out_file=docx_file + "-out.docx"

document.save(out_file)

print("\n File saved to: ", out_file)
```

Thank you,
Lapyiu Ho

Comment: This is extracting only one link...

Comment: I did the test , the code just extract only partial links of the doc

Answer (score 1):

```
def iter_hyperlink_rels(rels):
   for rel in rels:
      if rels[rel].reltype == RT.HYPERLINK:
         yield rels[rel]
```

This would remove the error.

Comment: Please edit your answer to have correctly formatted code (Use Ctrl+K on the section to be formatted). Also, added to the code segment please include an explanation as to why it works so that future readers would know what the answer does.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to this party, but if you want something that pulls all the links out of .docx files and makes a spreadsheet of them (or returns a list of them), I have a script that might do that for you. It includes both the URL and the linked text, and you can feed it a whole folder if you want.

https://github.com/Colin-Fredericks/hx_util/blob/master/hx_util/GetWordLinks.py

It uses BeautifulSoup and UnicodeCSV, both of which you can also grab from that same repo. Runs in Python3. Instructions at the top of the file. Handles non-ascii characters. Only tested on Mac and Ubuntu so far. Excel does not reliably import Unicode CSVs, though Google Drive does. Offer void() where prohibited.

Comment: Link is broken. It is not recommended to have answers depending too much on external websites.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. Thanks for the note - I fixed the link. It's a 250-line file, so I'm not sure what the best way to include the code here would be.

Comment: I'm actually not sure either. You can probably find the answer in the META of StackOverflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using the following code to print the hyperlink content from docx

```
from docx import Document
from docx.opc.constants import RELATIONSHIP_TYPE as RT

document = Document('test.docx')
rels = document.part.rels

def iter_hyperlink_rels(rels):
    for rel in rels:
        if rels[rel].reltype == RT.HYPERLINK:
            yield rels[rel]._target      

print(iter_hyperlink_rels(rels)
```