# How to extract the all hyperlink and their text from a word document using python

Tags: python, ms-word, hyperlink, docx, python-docx

I've been trying to extract all the hyperlinks in a document and their associated texts and then update the links where "text" matches some keywords. I can extract all the hyperlinks via the following code:

```
import docx
from docx import Document
from docx.opc.constants import RELATIONSHIP_TYPE as RT

document = Document('test.docx')
rels = document.part.rels

for rel in rels:
    if rels[rel].reltype == RT.HYPERLINK:
        hyperlink_rel = rels[rel]
        hyperlink = hyperlink_rel._target
        print(hyperlink)

document.save("test.docx")
```

but I can't get the text and apply the condition. Here is what I want:

```
for rel in rels:
    if rels[rel].reltype == RT.HYPERLINK:
        hyperlink_rel = rels[rel]
        hyperlink = hyperlink_rel._target
        text = hyperlink_rel._text
        if text == "jira link":
            hyperlink_rel._target = "www.example.com"
```

First, I need to get all the hyperlinks and associated texts. Then, based on the condition, update the hyperlink with new URL.

To clarify, let's say I've three hyperlinks in my doc as Jira1, Jira2 and Jira3. Now I want to get all of three hyperlinks which may direct to "www.jira.com" and the name of the hyperlinks that is Jira1,Jir2 and Jira3.

Comment: What do you mean by "Extracting the hyperlink"?

Comment: It means I want to get all the hyperlinks from my word document.

Lets say I've 3 hyperlinks in my document.

Jira_1,
Jira_2, and
Jira_3 

Now I want to get the name of the hyperlink plus the link of the hyperlink. I hope now it gets clear. @BlueRobin

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40475757/how-to-extract-the-url-in-hyperlinks-from-a-docx-file-using-python Answer your question?

Comment: @BlueRobin this will only give me hyperlinks. I won't fetch the hyperlink text. If you have any idea how to do that then kindly let me know. Thankyou

Comment: What do you mean by hyperlink text? Do you mean getting the information of a web page? If so, try using the requests module,

Comment: No man. Let's say I have a hyperlink in a document named as "jira link" which contains a link to "www.jira.com" ,Now I want to get both the name of the hyperlink "jira link" and the actual link that is "www.jira.com" @BlueRobin

Comment: I see now. This is most certainly not a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, It won't but it doesn't matter even if it duplicates as I just need the link and text.

Answer (score 0):

try this, you can adjust the print into a variables or any outputs

```
from docx import Document
  
doc = Document(<insert_full_path>)
para_lines = 0

print("[")
for line in doc.paragraphs:
    if len(line.hyperlinks) > 0 :
        for link in line.hyperlinks:
            print("{")
            print(f"line: {para_lines},")
            print(f"url_text: {link.text},")
            print(f"url_raw: {link.address},")
            print(f"full_text: {line.text},")
            print("}")
            print(f",")
        
    para_lines += 1
print("]")
```